# Render PDF in page and get form fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to render pdf in my webform page and that pdf have multiple form fields so user will fill up those fields from page itself and also want those field values back in my webform post on clicking button.

Comment: Firstly, what have you tried? Secondly, my hunch would be this is not possible - although this may help a bit http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PdfGenerator_CS06162007023347AM/PdfGenerator_CS.aspx

Comment: I still searching for the solution. As I want to render page in webform itself and then user fillup fields in page and then submit to save pdf.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want here. Is the form in your web page, or in the PDF? Please add into your question the code you have thus far.

Comment: @Keyur why a pdf? why cant it just be a normal form? are you scanning in existing physical forms and want to get them filled in on your site? do you have existing pdf's with questions on and you dont want to make a form so just want to have it load the pdf up?

Comment: yes I want pdf directly to render in page where user can fill in fields and save pdf

Answer (score 0):

try [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), it has features to fill the form.

```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"c:\existing.pdf");

    FileStream out = new FileStream(@"C:\newForm.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, out);           

    TextField field = new TextField(stamp.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(40, 500, 360, 530), "some_text");

   // add the field here, the second param is the page number  you want it on         
    stamp.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField(), 1);

    stamp.FormFlattening = true; // lock fields and prevent further edits.

    stamp.Close();
```

visit this site for tutorial [Pdf Form filling c#](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030211-1.aspx)

Comment: I want to render pdf directly in my webform browser where user will fill data in fields of pdf and submit to save it.

Comment: then you need to read the contents, try setting response.header content dispostion to inline.